# Use sphinx to generate c++ documentation

Tags: python, c++, python-sphinx

I'm working on a python and C++ project and want to generate a global html documentation. For the python part I already setup sphinx to generate the documentation. This is working like a charm.

But now there comes the C++ part. 
First I installed breathe through pip and followed the [quick start guide](https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

To make testing easier I created simple C++ project with only one class.
I also created the needed xml files with doxygen.

Now I want sphinx to generate the documentation. I issued `sphinx-quickstart`  with everything in default. After that I added the following lines to the `conf.py` file:

```
extensions = ['breathe']
# -- Options for Breathe
breathe_projects = { "test": "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/testDocu/xml" }
breathe_default_project = "test"
```

I also changed the `index.rst` to look like this:

```
.. Test documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Wed Jul 19 09:18:10 2017.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Test's documentation!
================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

.. doxygenclass:: MyClass
   :members:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

But when I now run `make html` I get the following error message:

```
Exception occurred:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/transforms/universal.py", line 290, in apply
    txtnode.parent.replace(txtnode, nodes.Text(newtext)) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-fLAGKW.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers. Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time. A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks! make: *** [html] Error 1
```

Is this a know bug or am I doing something wrong?